# How can i align this button to the left of the screen

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

How can i align this button to the left of the screen?

```
RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  elevation: 2,
                  focusElevation: 4,
                  hoverElevation: 4,
                  highlightElevation: 8,
                  disabledElevation: 0,
                  onPressed: () { },
                  child: Text(
                      'Pay Now',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: If all those widgets are children of a `Column` use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your parent Widget is Column Then use like this:

```
 column(
      crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start
  children:[
        
  ...... your widgets.

   
        ]

        )
```